# Квадраты вместо шрифтов Arcolinux (Arch)

Tags: шрифты, archlinux

Во многих программах (figma, discord,...) которые ставил из snap-store вместо надписей отображаются квадраты. Как починить? terminus-font установлен.

locale -a

```
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
```

[image: Пример]

Comment: шрифты поставь от убунту

Comment: @eri Я поставил Arcolinux, отключил все шрифты кроме одного, который без кириллицы, и дискорд продолжил корректно работать! https://transfer.sh/HMzzC/sh_0181.png Как я понимаю, шрифты встроены в это electron - приложение. При отладке через strace идет поиск шрифта, но он используется исключительно при отрисовке заголовка окна. На шоте у ТС показан попап, и скорее всего его рисует ... ну не сам discord напрямую, а оболочка рабочего стола. ТС, нужны подробности на счет какая оболочка, были какие-то манипуляции со шрифтами, и проблема только с попапом, а в главном окне программы все в порядке?